# Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge keeps freezing/restarting randomly

Tags: samsung, reboot, system-freeze

This issue started yesterday. I was playing Hearthstone but all of a sudden, my phone froze for about 30 seconds and then restarted. I went on my phone again but this time it was frozen and I had to leave it overnight to discharge. Today I found a way to restart the phone if it is frozen by pressing `Power` + `Volume Down` but I still get freezes. Sometimes the phone just randomly restarts. Occasionally I get this thing with a flashing red light and I am unable to turn the phone on. I fix this by plugging in my phone to the charger but I don't want to keep doing that. I factory reset my phone but problem still persists.

P.S: My phone is hotter than usual.

Any ideas about what the problem can be and how to fix it?